# Coordinates of Folders or Files in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have been tasked to develop a module which requires me to get the coordinates of files in Windows Explorer.

Here is the use case:
My program opens up Windows Explorer into a certain folder (for example, C:\FavoriteVideo). The user does his arrangement of all the files and folders. There is a trigger for the program to save all the coordinates of the files and folders to a data structure (it may be a `Hashtable`) . I plan to use a Windows Service to perform this. (I am familiar with C#).

Please ask if you require any more information.

Comment: A Windows Service is not going to work. It has no idea what an individual user has configured his/her desktop to look like.

Comment: I have been googling the web and found out about how to create maximised Windows Explorer windows but nothing seems to come up for getting coordinates of the files/folders.

Comment: Hi Cody, my idea was to maximise the Windows Explorer window and then capture the coordinates. The absolute coordinates will help me develop some relative coordinate distance for smaller windows (or so I hope) :)

Comment: The point is not that this is an impossible task, just that you can't do it with a Windows Service. You'll need a normal user-mode application. If you want something that runs in the background, just don't create/show a window.

Comment: Basically, the Explorer just uses a `ListView`. You might try to get the window handle of that list view and then try to use the Windows API on the list view to find out information about the individual items. Cody Gray is right, by the way: A Windows service does not have access to a desktop application.

Comment: What is the end purpose for this?

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT: New information found with the location in the Registry]
Via a thread at http://help.lockergnome.com/windows2/Desktop-Icons-Position--ftopict450729.html I discovered that the Shell Bags registry keys, such as HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Shell/Bags/1/Desktop , seem to contain icon positioning information. Hope this helps!

I've heard that the Windows NT resource kit comes with layout.dll which exposes shell extension functions to retrieve and alter the user's icon layout. Perhaps that will work. I'm curious about this myself.

You might also try looking up how any of these programs do it, for example by looking at the symbols used therein:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/save-and-restore-desktop-icon-layout-in-windows-vista/

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/save-and-restore-the-position-of-desktop-icons-in-windows/

http://www.pchell.com/support/savedesktoplayout.shtml

Comment: Dead link, but it's commently known as Shell Bags and it's been known since 2004, Forensics keep it since it stores data even from deleted files.